# Client Puzzles and Amplification

Tags: hmac, security-definition

> [image]

Any hints or suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: By clicking near the start of the text and holding the left mouse button, then deftly moving the cursor toward the end of the text, and finally releasing the button, one can achieve an arcane action known as _selecting text_. Then, extra operations usually denoted "copy" and "paste" can be performed on the selected text, through popup menus or even, for users initiated to the dark arts of computing, with keyboard shortcuts. These technical operations can help avoiding the abomination of pushing a screenshot of text in a Q&A forum, as the _vulgus pecum_ is likely to do. You're welcome.

Comment: Did you just take a screenshot of your homework, including a question of the form ‘read the following article and echo back what it said’?

Comment: I vote to close this question, since it's not clear what the question is. This is a homework dumb, without even asking any specific question. It's not clear what has been done so far, what the problem is, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) - You'll need to make some assumptions about how $\mathrm{HMAC}_r(s)$ behaves. Suppose that it behaves like a random function i.e. the output is uniformly random. What is the probability that the last $n$ bits of the output are all $0$?

(b) - If the client does 1 unit of work (UoW) for every 64 UoW that the server does then how big does $n$ need to be to cause the client to do 64 UoW to correctly solve a puzzle? In other words for what value of $n$ is the expected number of $\mathrm{HMAC}_r(s)$ computations 64?

(c) - Read the section "Network Time Protocol attacks: as easy as (UDP port) 123" of the provided link, this is enough to answer this part.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing this helpful information. A quick question for part a. Assuming there are "a" total bits in the hash value and we want n last bits to be 0, does that mean that the client will take 2^(a - n) computations? Not sure if I followed your advice correctly. Also, the server would only take one try correct?